# Adding minutes to the publish time in wordpresss

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make the time to be set 10 minutes after the publish time. here is the code i use but it just gives me the publish time in results.

```
$convertedTime = get_the_time('H:i',$post->ID,strtotime('+10 minutes'));
echo get_the_date('m/d/Y ', $post->ID); 
echo $convertedTime;
```

I also tried something like this but no results

```
$minutesTimer = get_the_time('H:i', $post->ID);
$cenvertedTime = time('H:i',strtotime('+10 minutes',strtotime($minutesTimer))
```

Any Idea guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, [get_the_time()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) only accepts two arguments so passing more won't affect the output.

Get the post time in unix timestamp first and it's much easier;

```
// The offset in seconds
$offset = 60 * 10;

// 'U' gets the time as unix timestamp
$timestamp = get_the_time('U', $post->ID);

// Format the time and add the offset
$date = date('H:i', $timestamp + $offset);
```